# Restrict anonymous access to a Mediawiki site while putting a few pages on a white list of publicly accessible pages?

Tags: mediawiki, page, access-control, white-list

I have set up a Mediawiki using Bitnami through AWS, I have used the following in an attempt to restrict access unless a user logs in to the wiki.

```
# Disable reading by anonymous users
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;

# But allow them to read e.g., these pages:
$wgWhitelistRead =  [ "Main Page", "Help:Contents", "Special:RequestAccount" ];
```

This Results in all users not logged in to get the following "Login required" "Please log in to view other pages." On the Mainpage and the request account page.

How can I provide access to anon users to just these 3 pages while restricting viewing for all other pages as the white list doesn't look to work how I understand it should?

Comment: This is the correct approach, so you probably overwrite `$wgWhitelistRead` somewhere else or have some other incompatible extension / config setting.